# How to autoformat a text in Edit text to 00-0000-0000000-000 format in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, autoformatting

How can I autoformat a text typed in Edit text to `00-0000-0000000-000` format?
i.e. `2digits-4digits-7digits-(2/3)digits`. The `-` should be added automatically while typing.

I am using normal Android EditText.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Are you using Jetpack Compose TextField by any chance?

Comment: @Tonnie No.using xml layout only .

Comment: hi try this library it's not the same as you want but checks and modify https://github.com/Gary111/MaskedEditText

Comment: If you don't want to use a third party lib, you can add a TextWatcher and format the input by your self.

Comment: try this library same as you want
https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText

Comment: Managed to implement it using IBMAutoEditText